# Explain the compactness relation for elements of dcpos and also in a category if objects

Tags: category-theory, order-theory

The way below relation is used to define compact elements in a dcpo.  Can someone explain compactness and an object way below itself.  Also, when we abstract this relation to categories, where the order structure is represented by morphisms, please explain compactness in this sense too.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the nlab answers this really well.

**compact element in dcpo** https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/compact+element

**compact object in category theory** https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/compact+object